# MySQL search exact word with $ in word

Tags: mysql, perl, matching, cpu-word

I've been trying to find exact words and my research isn't helping me.

Solutions I've found:

```
$query .= "WHERE text REGEXP '[[:<:]]($word)[[:>:]]'";
// OR
$query .= "WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST('$word') ";
```

but neither are returning my matches.

I'm searching for stock symbols in my db (eg `$aapl`). And using `LIKE '%$word%'` will return `$bac` if you search for `$ba`.

Comment: post the "SHOW CREATE TABLE" output, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATCH AGAINST doesn't work exactly how you'd think it would.

This can be summarized by Casey Fulton as "...FULLTEXT searches only [return] anything if the number of results is less than 50% of the total table size..."

So instead, I'm searching for all the LIKEs and then filtering out exact words by a REGEX. I'm doing this to cut down on the process load for REGEX.

The following is my solution:

```
$likerows = "(SELECT * FROM `tweets` WHERE text LIKE '%$q%') AS likerows ";
$regexrows = "(SELECT * FROM $likerows WHERE text REGEXP('^.* $q .*$')) AS regexrows ";
$query = "SELECT * FROM $regexrows ";
```

I put spaces around the $q because I want to match a sentence-structured word (which is preceeded and followed by a space).

Also, I'm searching for "words" that start with $. This was an issue and here's what I did to solve that problem:

```
if(substr($q, 0, 1) == '$') $q = '\\\\' . $q; // you have to escape the backslash that escapes the $ -- it's nuts.
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use [**MySql Full Text Search**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) functions to accomplish what you describe above.

Enjoy!

Comment: I read that article previous to posting this question. I have enabled full text, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Jackson - if you are looking for a string literal then you need to use double quotes around the search term you are attempting to search for.  Also I believe the only table type that supports full text search is myisam and you do need to add full text indexes to the columns you are searching on as well.

Comment: I put in the string literal (thanks doug). I'm getting an error when I use the dollar sign though. Here's what I have:

$query .= "WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST(\"\$bac\") ";